# grass algorithm changes integer to fixed length

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, qgis-modeler

using grass v.clean in the graphical modeller it changes all integer values from the original file to int with length 9

Is this a standard behaviour?  Can this be avoided?

[image]

The details of the grass algorithm are the following

[image]

Comment: `v.clean`  with what options ?

Comment: @gene: break,rmdupl,rmsa.  I'll  add a screenshot to my question.